# Playing Multiple Sounds in Android

Tags: android

I want to Play Multiple sounds. I know how to play them, but i want to play them synchronously. For example i have all my sounds of length 4 second. if i play first sound at 04:00:00 and second play on 04:00:02 then the second one start on 04:00:04 not in middle.
Is there any framework available in android to do this Or any other Help...

Comment: what are you currently using? can you put some code so that we can suggest something along the lines of what you are doing.

Comment: are you using SoundPool to do this?

Comment: yes i am using soundpool